# How to grab value of read-only text field and use in angular js result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a textfield that is read only and pulling it's value from the query string. I can't get the value set in an output of javascript when bound with AngularJS.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control accountNumber" name="accountNumber" id="accountNumber" ng-model="accountNumber" ng-controller="main" data-placement="top" readonly>

function main($scope) {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var accountId = url.substr(url.indexOf("=") + 1);
  $scope.accountNumber = accountId; 
}
```

The account number needs to be placed into the "publisherId" field within the resulting javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnstatic.domain.com/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
var playerH = new Player({
 adTag:"{{adTag}}",
 fontElClass:"{{fontTag}}",
 playerClass:"{{playerClass}}",
 publisherId: "{{accountNumber}}"<===NEEDS TO BE REPLACED WITH VALUE FROM READ ONLY FIELD
});
});
</script>
```

To clarify:

1) `function main($scope){}` grabs the URL (which is also displayed in the textfield which is readonly), does some work on it and the value is stored in `accountId`.

2) That value is then supposed to be set in `$scope.accountNumber`, and used in the "publisherId:" field.

The resulting JavaScript is displayed to the user as text(not to be run on the page), and should have the `{{accountNumber}}` replaced with the value of the accountId.

The issue is that when the field is read only, its not showing the account number. It is also not setting the value in the publisherId field.

Comment: if your input is not `readonly` can you get the value?. If you can, try using `ng-readonly=true` instead.

Comment: @JeanCedron, the problem with setting it to `ng-readonly=true`, is that it doesn't set the value of the input based on "accountId"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my plnkr : [Link](http://embed.plnkr.co/Qro3R4kvqL7bx8LpSJzd/preview),

I think your problem is that your controller is not defined for the entire view, just for your input.

Comment: That's closer to what I'm looking for, but I can't get it to work with my version. http://jsfiddle.net/7xsnmwbn/

Comment: To simplify things, the account number doesn't have to be a text input. It could simply be a div with the value set: `<div class="accountNumber" name="accountNumber" id="accountNumber" data-placement="top"></div>`

If it makes it easier, we don't even need to display the account number in the form, it just has to display in the resulting javascript.

Comment: Interesting that if I set the angular module in its own file, and include that in the html, it works just fine and doesn't interfere.